# Not typing the full variable name but partial name is represented by another string value

Tags: c#

Lets say if `fields[0].ToString()` has string value of `"abc"`. Is there a way to declare `Classname.abc` by replacing the `"abc"` with `fields[z].ToString()`. 
So it would look like, `Classname.fields[z].ToString();`

So initially was doing it as shown below, which i think would be an inefficient way to do it(i have 200 lines of codes to type). `Split_CsvData[z]` contains the info I want to declare to the variables(eg. `Savestate.one_one_one`)

```
for (int z = 0; z < Split_CsvData.Length; z++)
{ 
    if(z==0)
        Savestate.one_one_one_grouping = Split_CsvData[z].ToString();
    else if (z == 1)
        Savestate.one_one_two_grouping = Split_CsvData[z].ToString();
    else if (z == 2)
        Savestate.one_one_three_grouping = Split_CsvData[z].ToString();
    else if(z == 3)
        Savestate.one_one_three_grouping = Split_CsvData[z].ToString();
    else if (z == 4)
        Savestate.one_one_four_grouping = Split_CsvData[z].ToString();
```

I'm wondering if its possible to do it this way? `fields[z].ToString()` contains the back part of the variable name, eg.(`one_one_one` OR `one_one_two`)

```
for (int z = 0; z < Split_CsvData.Length; z++)
{      
    Savestate.fields[z].ToString().Name = Split_CsvData[z].ToString();
}
```

Not looking for straight answer, but some hint would do! thanks for all ur help!

Comment: Not sure but seems like you are looking for some type of `Dictionary` [take a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You can use List for Savestate objects.

Comment: You could do this via reflection. Just search for "how to reference a member by its name in C#". However it´s very often a bad idea to do this, and I assume you´re better using some kind of a map that holds the name of the member you want to modifiy and the actual value. Just have a look at `Dictionary` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C# is a static language and does not have this type of "macro" substitution for member names.

You *could* use reflection to get the properties, saving the `PropertyInfo` objects in a dictionary, and using reflection *again* to set the properties dynamically, but that sounds like an ugly (and hard to debug) way to save a bit of slightly repetitive code.

Or, if you have control of the `Savestate` class, change it to be a data structure rather than having named properties.

Comment: Pretty vague for an answer IMHO.

Comment: @HimBromBeere "Not looking for straight answer, but some hint would do! " Vague answer for a vague question. You'd rather I coded up all of the reflection code?

Comment: No, I´d rather not answer vague questions at all.

Comment: thanks all for all ur help! i will try out see which method works out!